# Which address should request in sharded elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an index sharded on 2 nodes.
If I want to request using HTTP, Am I supposed to use any of the nodes hosts?

Will I get the same results if I request `GET /host1/_search` or `/host2/_search` ?

Comment: If you have cluster and you have added replica then you will get same results.

Comment: I don't use replica.

Comment: You need not specify node in your search. Making a search on the index will get you results from all shards for that index